# Combine multiple enums into master enum list

Tags: c#, enums, combinations

Is it possible to combine multiple enums together?  Below is code sample of what I would like to see:

```
enum PrimaryColors
{
   Red,
   Yellow,
   Blue
}

enum SecondaryColors
{
   Orange,
   Green,
   Purple
}

//Combine them into a new enum somehow to result in:
enum AllColors
{
   Red,
   Orange,
   Yellow,
   Green,
   Blue,
   Purple
}
```

It does not matter what order they are, or what their backing numbers are, I just want to be able to combine them.

For context, this is so that multiple classes for a program I am working on would have enums associated with what they do.  My main program would read all of the enums available from each of the support classes and make a master list of available enums of available commands (the the enums are for).

Edit:
The reason for these enums is because my main program is reading in a list of commands to perform at certain times, and so I want to read in the file, see if the command in it is associated with one of my enums, and if it is, put it into a list of commands to perform.

Comment: `enum` is fundamentally a compile-time concept. Are you looking to produce a C# file that contains a definition of something similar to `AllColors`, or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Are you trying to create the combined type `AllColors` programmatically, I mean, not create it until your application is running? If you just want to add them into a list, remember that all enums have `System.Object` and `System.Enum` as their base classes. You could create some list based on one of those classes. Your enum values would be boxed, of course, but that's probably not a problem.

Comment: Why limit yourself to `enums`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am basically making a program that handles different things via support files.  So if a "legs" enum had values of "walk" and "dance", and an arms enum had values of "grasp" and "wave", then I want the limbs enum to know that the possible actions are "walk", "dance", "grasp", and "wave".  I am trying to keep enums associated with certain support files in those support files to decrease coupling between the main program and its support files.

Comment: Why don't you simply use lists of strings where each string represents a command?

Comment: I added a little more context above.  Also, it would be okay if they were boxed to some extent like Allcolors.PrimaryColors.Red.

Comment: What are you going to do about same enums? For instance, "fingers" and "toes" can both "grasp" and "wiggle". But that might be all the shared functionality--- for instance, "fingers" can "gesture" and "sign" while toes cannot.

Comment: @kol I am seriously considering your suggestion about using a list of strings.  They are far easier to work with in this situation, and I'm using a switch to determine which string is associated with it anyway.

Comment: @StarPilot In this case, I would make the rule of unique names only, since I am reading in a list of commands to perform, they have to be unique there.  So I would have something like fingersGrasp, fingersWiggle, toesGrasp, etc.

Comment: Similar to TypeScript: enum eX = eA & eB. It would be nice to combine two existing enumerations in .NET to adhere to the DRY concept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure I understand precisely. But you can make a `List<>` of all the values like this:

```
var allColors = new List<Enum>();

allColors.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PrimaryColors)).Cast<Enum>());
allColors.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SecondaryColors)).Cast<Enum>());
```

Instead of `List<Enum>` you could also use `HashSet<Enum>`. In any case, because you assign a `PrimaryColor` or `SecondaryColor` to a *class* type (namely `System.Enum`), you get [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), but that's just a technical detail (probably).

Comment: BTW, `HashSet` most likely doesn't make sense here as a performance optimization. But it could make sense if you're using it to make the intent more clear.

Comment: This code does not appear to work when I tried it.  In a sample program based on this, I got the errors:  `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Enum>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Enum>)' has some invalid arguments` and `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication1.Program.PrimaryColors>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Enum>'`

Comment: @svick Agree. By the way, there's a great risk that the hash codes of the different types collide, for example `Red` collides with `Orange`, and so on. So it's not for the performance of it. The instance method `Equals(object)` does however work fine (it is overridden by enums to check the type of the argument, and then check if the underlying integer value agrees).

Answer (score 7):

> The reason for these enums is because my main program is reading in a list of commands to perform at certain times, and so I want to read in the file, see if the command in it is associated with one of my enums, and if it is, put it into a list of commands to perform.

This seems like you don't want three different `enum` types, you want one type (what you call “master `enum`”) plus some way to decide which of the sub-enums a certain value belongs to. To do that, you can use a collection of values from your master enum, or a `switch`.

For example:

```
enum Color
{
   Red,
   Orange,
   Yellow,
   Green,
   Blue,
   Purple
}

bool IsPrimaryColor(Color color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case Color.Red:
    case Color.Yellow:
    case Color.Blue:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also, [you should use a singular name for `enum` types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx) (unless it's a flag `enum`).

Answer (score 4):

You can derive the sub-groups from the complete group.
An example:

```
enum AllColors 
{
   Red,
   Orange,
   Yellow,
   Green,
   Blue,
   Purple
}

enum PrimaryColors
{
   Red = AllColors.Red,
   Yellow = AllColors.Yellow,
   Blue = AllColors.Blue
}

enum SecondaryColors
{
   Orange = AllColors.Orange,
   Green = AllColors.Green,
   Purple = AllColors.Purple
}
```

Comment: This works, but be careful if you're going in the reverse, i.e. deriving the group from the subgroups; unless you assign non-overlapping int values to the subgroup items, you will get overlapping items in the complete group.  Not technically illegal, but a potential problem if you're not expecting it.  [Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JuLG2c).

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple and just use the implicit `int` conversions, or use the `System.Enum.Parse()` function:

```
enum PrimaryColors
{        
    Red = 0,
    Yellow = 2,
    Blue = 4
}

enum SecondaryColors
{
    Orange = 1,
    Green = 3,
    Purple = 5
}

//Combine them into a new enum somehow to result in:
enum AllColors
{
    Red = 0,
    Orange,
    Yellow,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Purple
}

class Program
{
    static AllColors ParseColor(Enum color)
    {
        return ParseColor(color.ToString());
    }
    static AllColors ParseColor(string color)
    {
        return (AllColors)Enum.Parse(typeof(AllColors), color);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrimaryColors color1=PrimaryColors.Red;
        AllColors result=(AllColors)color1;
        // AllColors.Red

        SecondaryColors color2=SecondaryColors.Green;
        AllColors other=(AllColors)color2; 
        // AllColors.Green

        AllColors final=ParseColor(PrimaryColors.Yellow);
        // AllColors.Yellow
    }
}
```