# C# Creating a primary enum list that has dependant enum sublists

Tags: c#, list, enums

Primary List:

```
enum CarMake
{
   Ford, Toyota, Honda
}
```

Secondary List:

```
enum CarModel
{
  Explorer, // Ford
  Corolla, // Toyota
  Camry, // Toyota
  Civic, // Honda
  Pilot //  Honda

}
```

Is there some means of linking the 2 enum lists together?

So that when using CarMake the program will know which CarModels are linked?

Answer (score 1):

No, as you want to achieve is not possible, but it would be possible using `Dictionaries` and string for `CarModel`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<CarMake,string[]>();

dict.Add(CarMake.Ford, new string[] { "Explorer" });
dict.Add(CarMake.Toyota, new string[] { "Corolla","Camry" });
dict.Add(CarMake.Honda, new string[] { "Civic","Pilot" });
```

then if you want to retrieve the cars from Honda, you call it as shown below:

```
var hondaCars = dict[CarMake.Honda]
```

If you, instead, want to retrieve the car-maker from the model you just call:

```
var carMaker = dict.FirstOrDefault(key => key.Value.Contains("Civic")).Key
```

Comment: You could even make it a `Dictionary<CarMake, List<CarModel>>`.

Comment: @juharr thanks, I have added the possibility of retrieving either the cars from the manufacturer, or the manufacturer from the car.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into this.

[Combine multiple enums into master enum list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734746/combine-multiple-enums-into-master-enum-list)

```
allCars.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarModel)).Cast<Enum>());
allCars.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarMake)).Cast<Enum>());
```

Since if you make the list carModel into a master list in theory you get your answer