# C# enum type shared multiple classes

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to find what is the most elegant way to handle the below situation:

```
class ObjectA
{
    public enum MandatoryParameters {A, B, C}
    public enum OptionalParameters {D, E, F}
}
class ObjectB
{
    public enum MandatoryParameters {G, H, I}
    public enum OptionalParameters {J, K}
}
class Error
{
    MandatoryOrOptionalParameters param;
    string errorDescription;

    Error(MandatoryOrOptionalParameters p, string d)
    {
        param = p;
        errorDescription = d;
    }
}
```

Is there any good way to create a `MandatoryOrOptionalParameters` type to avoid `string`? I read the few related message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734746/combine-multiple-enums-into-master-enum-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582477/combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where your solution Y would be _"I know, I'll use enums"_, which is a suboptimal solution for problem X to begin with. Explain why you chose enums in the first place, and how you're going to use them, so perhaps a better design altogether can be suggested.

Comment: Check flags attribute for enum type

Comment: Smart comment CodeCaster :-) I had this feeling when posting. The enum values represent the object attributes which are filled during the serialization process. I am using the enum types for 1) loop through mandatory and check if null value => raise error, 2) create a list of validation errors to be displayed in the form of Field/ErrorDescription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an enum representing any kind of parameters and then each class will get or specify a collection of items representing the optional or the mandatory:

```
public enum Parameters { A, B, C, D, E }

// Class specifies for itself the mandatory and optional
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<Parameters> Mandatory { get; set; } = new List<Parameters> { A, B };

    public IEnumerable<Parameters> Optional { get; set; } = new List<Parameters> { C, D };
}

// Class receives what are the mandatory and optional
public class Bar
{
    public Bar(IEnumerable<Parameter> optional, IEnumerable<Parameter> mandatory)
    {
        // store input
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, you can use [flag] attribute too :P

Comment: @sTrenat - True, if one chooses the option like in `Foo` then having an attribute class to specify it is a nice way too

Comment: Wow  sounds elegant, let me give it a try and feedback.

Comment: @Salim - I'd personally go with the second option as it better fits with SOLID :)

Comment: constructor of Bar takes two same parameters. so its error prone.

Comment: Well done @GiladGreen! You definitely nailed down my problem! Many thanks!